# How to add random class/id to each dom element in react app dynamically

Tags: reactjs

1. Is there a way to add class/id to each DOM element in React app dynamically?
2. Can we do this at the time of bundling?
3. Is it a good idea to give class/id to each DOM element?

Sample Image - added random class to each DOM element

[image]

Comment: can you clarify exactly what you are asking? you can absolutely add dynamic classes to react components, not sure about what you mean by number 2, there is no problem giving classes/ids to components

Comment: Reacts virtual dom does this automatically. (if i'm understanding your question correctly)

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely. You can do this. But there's no point in adding random classes.

What you see in the snippet of code you posted is nothing like randomness. It's simply encoding classes to smaller class names to optimise the code size, making it faster for the client to download.

You might wanna take a look at [obfuscating javaScript code](http://ajaxian.com/archives/utility-javascript-obfuscator) and [minifying](https://github.com/mrclay/minify) assets. This is a huge subject that's not really worth it until your codebase is large enough.